# Anisble XML module encoding issue

Tags: ansible

While trying to save the value with the one mentioned below, the module is encoding the tags with `&lt;![CDATA[...]]&gt;`

How can I add these tags?

```
    tasks:
  - name: Inserting
    xml:
      path: /usr/local/abc/var/apps/active/app/etc/xyz.xml
      xpath: /config/admin/args/frontValue
      value: <![CDATA[proxy]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<![CDATA[` is merely a *human* convenience, and means nothing to the XML file. In the same way that `hello` can be written as `&#x68;&#x65;&#x6c;&#x6c;&#x6f;` but no one would chose to encode the characters that way, so too the string `proxy` is equivalent to `<![CDATA[proxy]]>`

If your target application is not using an XML parser, and is looking for the literal characters `<![CDATA[`, then you are in a situation where you shouldn't use the `xml:` module for fixing that problem and use something that allows more fine-grained control over the output characters.